# GCP alerting policies based on percentage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, monitoring

I am trying to create some alerting policies in GCP for my application hosted in `Kubernetes` cluster.
We have a Cloud load balancer serving the traffic and I can see the HTTP status codes like `2XX`, `5XX` etc.

I need to create some alerting policies based on the error percentage rather than the absolute value like `((NumberOfFailures/Total) * 100)` so that if my error percentage goes above say 50% then trigger an alert.

I couldn't find anything on the google documentation. It just tells you to use `counter` which is like using an absolute value. I am looking for something like if the `failure rate` goes beyond 50% in a rolling window of 15 minutes then trigger the alert.

Is that even possible to do that natively in `GCP`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think this is possible with [MQL](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference). I have recently created something similar to your use case.

```
fetch api
    | metric 'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/api/request_count'
    | filter
        (resource.service == 'my-service.com')
    | group_by 10m, [value_request_count_aggregate: aggregate(value.request_count)]
    | every 10m
    | { group_by [metric.response_code_class],
        [response_code_count_aggregate: aggregate(value_request_count_aggregate)]
    | filter (metric.response_code_class = '5xx')
        ; group_by [],
    [value_request_count_aggregate_aggregate:
        aggregate(value_request_count_aggregate)] }
    | join
    | value [response_code_ratio: val(0) / val(1)]
    | condition gt(val(), 0.1)
```

In this example, I am using the request count for a service my-service.com. I am aggregating the request count over the last 10 minutes and responses with response code 5xx. Additionally, I am aggregating the request count over the same time period, but all response codes. Then in the last two lines, I am computing the ratio of the number of 5xx status codes with the number of all response codes. Finally, I create a boolean value that is true when the ratio is above 0.1 and that I can use to trigger an alert.

I hope this gives you a rough idea of how you can create your own alerting policy based on percentages.